# Why does this drop me into LDB in SBCL?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

This code drops me into the LDB in SBCL from SLIME but not the termial:

```
(declaim (optimize debug)) ;; inhibit tail-call optimization
(defun stackoverflow () ;; infinite recursion
  (stackoverflow))
(unwind-protect
    (stackoverflow)
  (stackoverflow)) ;; called during handler for the first stack overflow
```

Why does this crash SBCL from SLIME but not the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that a valid (ANSI) Common Lisp implementation is allowed to ignore any declarations except the `special` declaration. I guess the SLIME REPL has slightly different behavior here (since it is not the same as the sbcl toplevel - it adds some things like reuse of previous results)